# Serializing object to list/dictionary of key value pairs

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

0Is there an existing method in .NET which would allow me to serialize (and deserialize) an objects public properties and any child properties into a set of key value pairs?

What I am after is similar to how ASP MVC names inputs so for example the output might be:

```
PropA = 1
PropB = 2.3
PropC.SubPropA = "Test"
PropC.SubPropB = False
PropD[0].Name = "John"
PropD[0].Name = "Jack"
PropD[1].Age = 30
PropD[1].Age = 60
```

It should be able to handle collections, primitives, value types and custom classes similar to how the XmlSerializer can.

I would prefer to use an existing method if it exists as this would be more likly to handle things like primitives, enums, lists, custom classes etc correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has also been my problem and I what I know as of date is that there is no good way to serialize / represent key value pairs in XML. What I did for my problem is to create a custom class which served as a wrapper with properties that are also custom classes.

If you really want to serialize then here is an example (but I'm sorry it is in C# and I could find a vb.net example)

https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/one-way-to-serialize-dictionaries/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think you've misunderstood. I want to serialize an object with various properties (primitive, collections, classes) to a list of key value pairs where the key is the path for the value.